# Google maps: display alternate location if address not found

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to display a location on the map using the google maps iframe.

The **q** parameter value is set to the **address+city+state+country** fetched from the user data stored in the database.

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=34A (1st Floor), Jalan SS 267, Petaling Jaya, Selangor,Malaysia&layer=tc&t=m&z=15&source=embed&output=svembed"></iframe>
```

However, sometimes if the **q** parameters can't be displayed, although if is being copied and pasted  in the [maps.google.com](https://www.google.com.eg/maps) search field it will appear.

My question: is there are way to display the city and state as an alternate when the address in the **q** parameters can't be found?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can create a work around using the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#search_mode), but you will need an additional step.

You should get the latitude and longitude position of the city. For example, using the Geocoding API you can see that 'Petaling Jaya, Selangor,Malaysia' has coordinate 3.1278871,101.5944885

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DPetaling%2520Jaya%252C%2520Selangor%252CMalaysia

Now you can apply center and zoom parameters of Embed API to center your map at the city. The resulting URL will be

`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=34A%20(1st%20Floor)%2C%20Jalan%20SS%20267%2C%20Petaling%20Jaya%2C%20Selangor%2CMalaysia&center=3.1278871,101.5944885&zoom=13&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

**Examples**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Embed API</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe 
  
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=34A%20(1st%20Floor)%2C%20Jalan%20SS%20267%2C%20Petaling%20Jaya%2C%20Selangor%2CMalaysia&center=3.1278871,101.5944885&zoom=13&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU" width="600" height="400">
  
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Embed API</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe 
  
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=267%2C%20Jalan%20SS%202%2F2%2C%20Petaling%20Jaya%2C%20Selangor%2CMalaysia&center=3.1278871%2C101.5944885&zoom=13&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU" width="600" height="400">
  
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no way to provide alternative address, but you can position a map at the city.

Comment: Thanks. I used to load the maps without api key like the example I have written before. Even though if I use the api key with Google Maps Embed API, setting the center requires getting the coordinates of the place, which can't be done automatically based on the 'city+ state' data loaded from the database. I hope I found a programmatic way to do it.